# Trying to get Postgres setup in my environment but can't seem to get permissions to intidb

Tags: database, postgresql, chmod, chown

I'm following the recent RailsCast on setting up PostgreSQL, but I'm unable to run the `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres` command. Each time I run it, I get this error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "Construct".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_US.UTF-8.
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8.
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

creating directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not create directory "/usr/local/var": Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: I have the same issue...haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
# sudo mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres
# sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/var/postgres
# sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/var/postgres/
# initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

use your username in place of construct. So, if your computer username is WDurant, the code will be:

```
# sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/var/postgres/`

Comment: Sorry to hear you've been having such problems @Geuis. I should have added some context to indicate that I was just trying to show that `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/var/postgres/` is just a way to programmatically determine your username with `$(whoami)` instead of having to type it out as in `sudo chown wdurant /usr/local/var/postgres`. Hope you can get everything resolved, in any case. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @jhrr. Ugh sorry for the ugly comment last night. Wasn't really directed towards you personally. Just a lot of frustration on my end trying to get this setup. I deleted the prior comment but I'll leave this section here for anyone else that needs this in the future. "The issue isn't just the owner, its the permissions on the directory. No other answer has pointed out needing to adjust the directory perms. chmod 755 on the directory"

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Comment: Using homebrew, I followed the first three lines with `brew postinstall postgresql` and finally my issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 22):

If you run on Arch Linux, use like this :

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/postgres
sudo chmod 775 /var/lib/postgres
sudo chown postgres /var/lib/postgres

sudo -i -u postgres

[postgres]$ initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'
[postgres]$ exit

sudo systemctl start postgresql.service

sudo -i -u postgres
```

Comment: Awesome - used to create custom data directory!  :-D

Comment: Perhaps consider adding this to the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL) ... the permission part is not yet explained I think

Comment: I followed these commands but still got a permission issue. I am non Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7):

You actually need to `SU` to the `postgres` user

- `sudo su - postgres`

then you can run the command

- `initdb -E UTF8` (I prefer setting this now because UTF8 is quite flexible and this will create all clusters as UTF8 [unless you explicitly specify otherwise])

then you need to create your user (if it hasn't already been created)

- `$ createuser -s -U postgres`
- `$ Enter name of role to add: {{ my login name }}` (this appears to be `Construct`)

then you can exit out of postgres user and you can create your own database

- `$ createdb`

Answer (score 3):

Which user are you running initdb as? If you're not root, you likely don't have permission to create directories in /usr/local. I suggest creating /usr/local/var/postgres as root, and chown'ing it to construct:

```
# mkdir -m 0700 -p /usr/local/var/postgres
# chown construct /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Then your initdb (run as construct) should have permission.

Also, note that Unix usernames are normally all-lowercase (but also case-sensitive); are you *sure* your Construct user is actually capitalized? If so, are you *really sure* your want it to be capitalized—-a lot of things will break.

(FYI: For Unix questions like this, you may find [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) provide quicker answers)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this should be, at least in CentOS/RHEL:

```
# install the binaries
sudo yum install -y postgresql-server
# create the database
sudo su postgres -c 'postgresql-setup initdb'
# enable the service to start on VM start
sudo systemctl enable postgresql.service
# start the service
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```

Then you can access it with

```
sudo -u postgresql psql
```